# How to exclude sub folders

Tags: powershell

I want to get all "*.exe" files from one folder. It has 3 sub folders. but I want get files from 2 sub folders only. I am trying to use `-Exclude` in PowerShell. It is working to exclude single file but it is not working to exclude a folder. can anybody tell how to solve it.

This is what I am using the below code it is working to exclude "HWEMNGR.EXE" etc files but Its not allowing me to exclude a sub folder from main folder.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\depot\main" -Recurse -Include "*.exe" -Exclude HWEMNGR.EXE,wmboot.exe,SDClientMobileEdition.exe | % { $_.FullName }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-Exclude` is good for file names however it does not have a good track record for folder name\path exclusion. You should use a `Where-Object` clause to address that.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\depot\main" -Recurse -Include "*.exe" -Exclude "HWEMNGR.EXE","wmboot.exe","SDClientMobileEdition.exe" | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | 
    Where-Object{$_ -notmatch "\\FolderName\\"}
```

The snippet `% { $_.FullName }` was replaced by `Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName` which does the same thing. Then we use `Where-Object` to exclude paths where FolderName is not there. It is regex based so we double up on the slashes. This also helps make sure we exclude folders and not a file that might be called "FolderName.exe"

**Alternate approach**

Like [TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245749/themadtechnician) points out you could come at this from another direction and just ensure the files come from the only two folders you really care about. `Get-ChildItem` will take an array for paths so you could also use something like this.

```
$paths = "D:\depot\main\install","D:\depot\main\debug"
$excludes = "HWEMNGR.EXE","wmboot.exe","SDClientMobileEdition.exe"
$Files = Get-ChildItem $paths -Filter "*.exe" -Exclude $excludes | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

`$paths` is the only two folders you want results from. You still exclude the files you dont want and then just return the full file paths.

Comment: Because of the fact that you have to get everything and then exclude, if it only has 2 subfolders that he wants it may be faster to get the root folder and then get the 2 subfolders that he wants recursively. That way he isn't getting the third folder's contents, and then excluding it. For small sets like this sometimes a little extra work up front is worth the time in the end.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Included a suggestion based on your comment. Assuming I understood.....

Comment: Yeah, looks about right. Might want to include 'D:\Depot\Main' in the paths.

Answer (score 0):

I will take the following **example** to explain how I do it:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\a -include "*.txt" -recurse | %{$_.fullname}

C:\a\b\b1.txt
C:\a\b\b2.txt
C:\a\b\b3.txt
C:\a\c\c1.txt
C:\a\c\c2.txt
C:\a\c\c3.txt
C:\a\d\d1.txt
C:\a\d\d2.txt
```

Here under **C:\a**, the subfolders are **b,c and d**

Now I want *.txt files from **b and c** to be listed and I want to exclude any file under **d** subfolder.
To achieve this I introduce a **where (also used as "?")** condition as follows

```
Get-ChildItem C:\a -include "*.txt" -recurse | ?{$_.fullname -notlike "C:\a\d\*"}  | %{$_.fullname}

C:\a\b\b1.txt
C:\a\b\b2.txt
C:\a\b\b3.txt
C:\a\c\c1.txt
C:\a\c\c2.txt
C:\a\c\c3.txt
```

I hope this solves your problem.